# Why did the Medinan revelations turn violent?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad

If we look at the chronological Quran, it is clear that it seems to advocate peace and tolerance only before Mohammad's flight to Medina, and after, they turned inherently violent. Why?

For example:

> Quran (2:216) - "Fighting is prescribed for you, and ye dislike it. But it is possible that ye dislike a thing which is good for you, and that ye love a thing which is bad for you. But Allah knoweth, and ye know not."
>
> Quran (4:74) - "Let those fight in the way of Allah who sell the life of this world for the other. Whoso fighteth in the way of Allah, be he slain or be he victorious, on him We shall bestow a vast reward."
>
> Quran (8:12) - "(Remember) when your Lord inspired the angels... "I will cast terror into the hearts of those who disbelieve. Therefore strike off their heads and strike off every fingertip of them"
>
> Quran (8:39) - "And fight with them until there is no more fitna and religion is all for Allah"
>
> Quran (9:5) - "So when the sacred months have passed away, then slay the idolaters wherever you find them, and take them captive and besiege them and lie in wait for them in every ambush, then if they repent and keep up prayer and pay the poor-rate, leave their way free to them."

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have this idea that Islam was a Buddhism-like religions that was okay with all religions and completely pacifistic before Madinah. That is a ridiculous idea. Islam didn't suddenly turn violent or anything. Islam has always said that it is the true religion, and that all other religions lead to hell. In fact, many Makki Ayaat have descriptions of Hellfire.

Allah always said that the people of Makkah were doing Zulm (transgression). So, when the Muslims gained power in the land, Allah commanded them to fight against their Zulm.

> If any one you sees something objectionable, he should change it with his hand if he can change it with his hand. But if he cannot (do so), he should do it with his tongue, and if he cannot (do so with) his tongue he should do it in his heart, that being the weakest form of faith. ([Sunan Abu Dawood](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/50))

As you can see above, if you see something bad and you don't have any power to stop it, you at least speak against it. When you have the power, you use the power (hand) to stop it.

This is exactly what is shown in the Quran. When the muslims didn't have the power it only spoke against Zulm. When they got the power (in Madinah), they are commanded to fight against the Zulm.